# Getting the Reference URL from form element using hidden field(PHP, HTML form)

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, url

I have an website and have multiple projects. All the project pages has contact us button and its redirected to contact page with form integrated. So **i want to find from which URL they are coming and filling the form**. I am using pure HTML, CSS website and PHP for form submission.

Thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options come to my mind:

- Easiest and recommended: you redirect adding a query parameter (eg, refirect to: contact.php?from=page1 instead of just contact.php) then read the 'from' value via PHP $_GET
- You can also use the http-referrer header from PHP (i.e. read $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']), but this may be unreliable

You could also get more creative: you could set a cookie via JS just before redirecting :) There are possibly many other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get request to achieve this task.

While redirection:

```
www.xyz.com/contact.php?form=project1
www.xyz.com/contact.php?form=project2
```

In Contact.php

```
if($_GET[from] == "project1")
{
   // he is coming from project1
   // Do something 
}
```

You can use switch also.